# Programically call sharepoint to a view

Tags: development, view

How Can I call programically from the view ? I have got a List from CRM but it's only a view no column have been created.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have SPView object and you want to add columns to it.

Comment: No I want to read a object from External Lists, like this:
`
            queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='DataPoc' /><FieldRef Name='DataKon' /><FieldRef Name='Nazwisko' /><FieldRef Name='Imie' />";
            queryPoszczegolnyUrlop.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

            SPListItemCollection listaDniUrlopow = witryna1.Lists["Urlopy"].GetItems(queryPoszczegolnyUrlop);
            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniUrlopow in listaDniUrlopow)
            {`

Comment: What do you mean by "I have got a List from CRM but it's only a view no column have been created." Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: My Sharepoint Administrator told me that it is a External List. I must call it from Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this doesn't make much sense. I mean if there is an external list, you can browse it and check which columns are there. Anyways, I think you can get which fields are there in the list via code by doing something like this.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
{
     string displayName = field.Title;
     string internalyName = field.InternalName;   
}
```

Comment: No no. I hve got imported list from a CRM by a View like a External lists. But i don't cnow how to use a Calm for this. I read this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-get-all-the-external-content-types-in-sharepoint-2010/ I want to lists some fields from External List by CAML